# Beginner. Having trouble getting NGINX to work.

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx

I'm diving into web development but I'm having troubles getting Nginx to work on my Ubuntu-OS computer. Firstly, localhost in my browser brings up an "Unable to Connect" page. I tried restarting Nginx and here's what I got:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "pass" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:62
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I actually had it working yesterday where the page said "Welcome to Nginx" except the only problem then was that I couldn't get the phpinfo page to show up. I probably dwindled too much with the installation and configuration process. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should post the relevant part of your nginx configuration.

Answer (score 3):

```
unknown directive "pass" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:62
```

Your configuration is invalid, with the problem being on line 62 of that file. There is no `pass` directive -- you probably want `proxy_pass` or `fastcgi_pass`.